# Use LineIterator to access pixel intensity values along a line

Tags: c++, ios, swift, opencv, image-processing

I am completely new to opencv, so I would like to have help with my task. I have built a drawing iOS App using Swift. The user is able to draw lines and returns an array of the pixel locations in (x, y) of the endpoints. The canvas on which the user draws is the same size as a picture the user can select. I would like for LineIterator to access the pixel intensity values of the image along the lines that are defined by the array of endpoints. Since the lines are segmented, I am thinking there would be a new LineIterator for each segment. Then, an array containing the pixel location and the corresponding intensity value is returned so that a chart can be graphed for these two values. So far, this is what I have in OpenCVWrapper.mm

```
+(NSMutableArray *) getPixelIntensity:(UIImage *)image withEndpoints:(NSMutableArray *) endpoints{

//Transform UIImage to cv::Mat cv::Mat imageMat; UIImageToMat(image, imageMat);

cv::LineIterator(image, endpoints[0], endpoints[1], 8, false); }
```

I am not sure how I should go about constructing the LineIterator object and accessing the pixel intensity value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `cv::LineIterator`, you could do something like this:

*Assuming 8-Bit, 3 channel image*

```
// grabs pixels along the line (pt1, pt2)
// from 8-bit 3-channel image to the buffer
LineIterator it(img, pt1, pt2, 8);
LineIterator it2 = it;
vector<Vec3b> buf(it.count);
for(int i = 0; i < it.count; i++, ++it)
    buf[i] = *(const Vec3b)*it;
// alternative way of iterating through the line
for(int i = 0; i < it2.count; i++, ++it2)
{
    Vec3b val = img.at<Vec3b>(it2.pos());
    CV_Assert(buf[i] == val);
}
```

The `vector<Vec3b> buff` contains the pixel values at points between pt1 and pt2, which you could use to plot graphs w.r.t. pt1 and pt2.

Following [this](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dc/dd2/classcv_1_1LineIterator.html#ac83a4c574ce6a50a78a52d7eee10371b) link, you can see what the flag `leftToRight` means and how you can use it to map pixel values from pt1 to pt2 or vice versa.

If the image is something else, other than `Vec3b`, you could use another type, for example `Vec3f` represents floating point values, `uchar` would be for single channel images and so on.

Hope it helps!

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html